# What is the hibernate annotations equivalent of this?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

```
 <one-to-one name="employee" class="com.test.study.model.employee" 
 cascade="save-update"> </one-to-one>
```

I'm thinking:

```
OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "com.test.study.model.employee", cascade = CascadeType.All)
```

But then, do I do the same thing in the other table as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
class Other{
    @OneToOne
    Employee employe;
}

class Employee {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "empolyee", cascade = CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    Other other;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.test.study.model.employee; 

@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private employee emp;
```